# how can I request a desktop site from inappbrowser cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I am requesting a website using cordova inappbrowser

> http://bugdevstudios.com/pixi/

This website works correctly if we load it via desktop but not from mobile. Do you have any idea what might be the issue? You can view the live website as well. When I load it from mobile using "Request Desktop Website" in chrome or firefox (mobile) it works.

Comment: check your console, there are errors when running the website from mobile or from chrome dev tools mobile emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inappbrowser doesn't support user-agent out of the box. Using a simple hack we may force inappbrowser to use cordova webview's user-agent-string.

Open your InAppBrowser.java and edit the run method.

```
WebSettings settings = inAppWebView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);              
settings.setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON);             
settings.setUserAgentString(thatWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString()); // magic line
```

Find more about "The Hack" [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3360)

Now to set cordova user agent string. we will use a plugin [cordova-useragent](https://github.com/LouisT/cordova-useragent)
List of user agent string can be found [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)